# Subtotales Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, group-by

Hola tengo mi tabla Abonos de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE Abonos(
    IdAbono             int,
    IdCliente           int,
    IdClientesdeCliente int,
    IdGiro              int,
    IdUsuario           int,
    Fecha               datetime,
    Periodo             int,
    Concepto            varchar(100),
    FormaPago           varchar(100),
    Cargo               numeric(18,2),
    Abono               numeric(18,2),
    Mensaje             varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO Abonos
VALUES
    (  1,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190101', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 210000 , ''),
    (  2,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190103', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 1000   , ''),
    (  3,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190102', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 10000  , ''),
    (  4,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190201', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 10000  , ''),
    (  5,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190204', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 10000  , ''),
    (  6,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190305', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 1000   , ''),
    (  7,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190307', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 1000   , ''),
    (  8,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190309', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 1000   , ''),
    (  9,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190410', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 20000  , ''),
    ( 10,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190417', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 20000  , ''),
    ( 11,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190501', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 200000 , ''),
    ( 12,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190503', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 20000  , ''),
    ( 13,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20200101', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 50000  , ''),
    ( 14,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20200101', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 50000  , ''),
    ( 15,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190108', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 111    , ''),
    ( 16,  1,  1, 12,  1, '20190109', 0, 'ARRENDAMIENTO', 'CHEQUE', 0, 1111   , '');

SELECT * FROM Abonos;

--GO
--DROP TABLE Abonos
```

Lo único que necesito es poner subtotales por mes de cada año pero no estoy seguro de comprender bien rollup o grouping sets.

Les agradezco.

Comment: Edita por favor y agrega lo que llevas hecho, para que a partir de eso la comunidad sepa como ayudarte

Comment: Tendrias que agrupar por mes y año y hacer la suma de lo que necesitas, aunque como comenta @Aprendiz seria mejor poner lo que ya tienes y si puedes la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: Es recomendable que los subtotales y totales los generes en la capa de presentación y no desde la base de datos. Así será más fácil identificarlos y darles el correcto formato.

Comment: Los subtotales son con base al campo abono cierto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las soluciones que han sido propuestas solo agrupan los datos por mes y año. Sin embargo, no consideraría eso como subtotales.

Una forma de hacerlo es agregando columnas que incluyan ese cálculo por medio de la cláusula OVER.

```
SELECT *,
    SUM(Abono) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Fecha), MONTH(Fecha)) AS Subtotal_Mes,
    SUM(Abono) OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(Fecha)) AS Subtotal_Año
FROM Abonos;
```

Si lo que te interesa es utilizar GROUPING SETS, debes entender que es muy probable que sólo puedas hacerlo con datos agrupados en distintos niveles. Aquí dejo un ejemplo.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN YEAR( fecha) IS NULL THEN 'Total Global'
            ELSE ISNULL(DATENAME(MM, fecha), 'SubTotal Anual') END AS Mes, 
        YEAR(fecha) AS Año, 
        SUM(abono)  AS Abono
FROM Abonos 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((MONTH(fecha), DATENAME(MM, fecha), YEAR(fecha)), --Subtotal por mes
                       (YEAR(fecha)), --Subtotal por año
                       ()) --Sin columnas para total global
ORDER BY ISNULL(YEAR(fecha), 10000), --ISNULL asegura que el total global aparezca al final
        ISNULL( MONTH(fecha), 13); --ISNULL asegura de que el subtotal anual aparezca al final
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que algo como esto necesitarias es cuestion de agrupar por mes y año

```
SELECT YEAR(Fecha) AS Año,DATENAME(MONTH,Fecha) AS Mes, SUM(Abono) AS Subtotal 
FROM Abonos
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,Fecha),YEAR(Fecha)
```

Aqui lo puedes verificar

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7182573a0df8d30d88f9b29d88114544

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es extraer el año y el mes de cada fecha, agruparlos por dichos campos. Cuando lo tengas agrupados, solo tendrás que hacer la suma del campo Abono para cada uno de los grupos.

```
SELECT MONTH(fecha), YEAR(fecha), SUM(abono) FROM Abonos GROUP BY MONTH(fecha), YEAR(fecha);
```